# Micro SD 32 GB shows up as 50 MB

Tags: sd-card

I just bought a Micro SD a month ago, now I want to use it and I plugged it in into my pc. The original size of the SD is 32 GB and on my PC it's showing up as 55MB, I also tried to format it and tried it on other devices. Is there anyway I can fix this problem? Or is it just completely broken?

Comment: Make sure that the entire sd card is formatted and not that there is 55 mb of partitioned space and 31 gigs of unpartitioned space. On a mac check disk utility and on windows check disk management.

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem is that the Micro SD card you bought is a fake.

If you suspect this, you can use a program that will fill it up with junk and determine what's the maximum size of junk it was able to fill the card with.

One such program that I know of is testdrive.exe which you may download here: http://www.schnapp.org/e-britain_ripoff/

I once ordered a fake Memory Stick Pro Duo and was able to figure it out with that program.